# SQL Server - Get All Month and Year numbers till current month from the Month and Year of joining

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have employee joining date, from the date of joining to till date i would like to print Month and Years numbers.

For instance employee has joining in July-2020, i need to get data as below

```
MonthNumber YearNumber
    7          2020
    8          2020
    9          2020
    10         2020
    11         2020
    12         2020
     1         2021
```

Below is my query, i am using a CTE and trying to increment it..

```
DECLARE @JoiningDate Date

SET @JoiningDate = '2020-07-04 11:21:03.827'

;With MonthYears as (
SELECT monthNumber = DATEPART(m, @JoiningDate),
       yearNumber = DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(m, i+1, @JoiningDate),
       i = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT monthNumber = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, i+1, @JoiningDate)),
       yearNumber = DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(m, i+1, @JoiningDate)),
       i = i+1
FROM MonthYears
WHERE DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, i+1, @JoiningDate)) <= DATEPART(m, GETDATE())
AND DATEPART(year, DATEADD(m, i+1, @JoiningDate)) <= DATEPART(year, GETDATE())
)
SELECT * FROM MonthYears
```

But i could see only 1 record, i.e  the month and year of joining which is 7, 2020

Comment: A hint perhaps: you don't need date arithmetics to solve your problem.  You will rarely find a year that has more or less than 12 months.

Comment: Your `WHERE` condition is wrong `DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, i+1, @JoiningDate)) <= DATEPART(m, GETDATE())`  `DATEPART(m, GETDATE())` will return `1` so next iteration will be `false` and you only get 1 row back.

Comment: Recursive CTE is much slower than a tally table or a calendar table to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is the `WHERE` condition

```
WHERE DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, i+1, @JoiningDate)) <= DATEPART(m, GETDATE())
AND DATEPART(year, DATEADD(m, i+1, @JoiningDate)) <= DATEPART(year, GETDATE())
```

On the second iteration, `Aug - 8` is not less than `DATEPART(m, GETDATE()) = 1`

I would use the first of the month date and increment by 1 month in the recursive CTE. Then use `DATEPART()` on the result

```
DECLARE @JoiningDate Date

SET @JoiningDate = '2020-07-04 11:21:03.827'

;With MonthYears as 
(
    SELECT [FirstOfMonth]   = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @JoiningDate), 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  [FirstOfMonth]  = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [FirstOfMonth])
    FROM    MonthYears
    WHERE   [FirstOfMonth]  < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
)
SELECT  *, 
        monthNumber = DATEPART(month, [FirstOfMonth]),
        yearNumber  = DATEPART(YEAR, [FirstOfMonth])
FROM    MonthYears
```

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating the requirement.
All you need is the dates which are the 1st day of each month and you can get them by starting with the 1st day of the month of `@JoiningDate` and adding 1 month recursively:

```
DECLARE @JoiningDate Date;
SET @JoiningDate = '2020-07-04 11:21:03.827';

WITH cte as (
  SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@JoiningDate), MONTH(@JoiningDate), 1) date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(m, 1, date)
  FROM cte
  WHERE DATEADD(m, 1, date) <= GETDATE()
)
SELECT MONTH(date) MonthNumber, 
       YEAR(date) YearNumber 
FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) -- you may need this because there may exist employees with more than 100 months of employement
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5c0d71ef4534983196bfd1b563511992).
Results:

```
> MonthNumber | YearNumber
> ----------: | ---------:
>           7 |       2020
>           8 |       2020
>           9 |       2020
>          10 |       2020
>          11 |       2020
>          12 |       2020
>           1 |       2021
```